# Does Enderton call Jech's proof of the recursion theorem wrong?

Tags: set-theory

I've been trying to learn from Jech's Set Theory book, but it seems to be seriously lacking in rigor (or perhaps I'm overlooking something). For example, here's Jech's proof of the recursion theorem:

> Let $$F(\alpha) = x \iff \textrm{there is a sequence } \langle \alpha_\zeta : \zeta < \alpha \rangle \textrm{ such that: } \ (1) \ (\forall \zeta < \alpha)(\alpha_\zeta = G(\langle \alpha_\eta : \eta < \zeta \rangle)) \textrm{ and } \ (2) \ x = G(\langle \alpha_\zeta : \zeta < \alpha \rangle).$$
> For every $\alpha$, if there is an $\alpha$-sequence that satisfies (1), then such a sequence is
> unique: If $\langle a_\zeta : \zeta < \alpha \rangle$ and $\langle b_\zeta: \zeta < \alpha \rangle$ are two $\alpha$-sequences satisfying (1), one
> shows $a_\zeta = b_\zeta$ by induction on $\zeta$. Thus $F(\alpha)$ is determined uniquely by (2), and therefore $F$ is a function. It follows, again by induction, that for each $\alpha$
> there is an $\alpha$-sequence that satisfies (1) (at limit steps, we use Replacement
> to get the $\alpha$-sequence as the union of all the $\zeta$-sequences, $\zeta < \alpha$). Thus $F$ is defined for all $\alpha \in \textrm{Ord}$. It obviously satisfies $F(\alpha) = G(F \upharpoonright \alpha)$. If $F'$ is any function on $\textrm{Ord}$ that satisfies $F'(\alpha) = G(F' \upharpoonright \alpha)$ then it follows by induction that $F'(\alpha) = F(\alpha)$ for all $\alpha$.

This seems to me an okay proof by induction. Enderton, however, seems to have something against this type of proof. This is what he says in his Elements of Set Theory, after proving the weaker theorem on $\omega$. Note that $(N, S, e)$ is here a model of the Peano axioms, where $N$ is the set of natural numbers, $S$ is the successor function and $e$ is the smallest element. $h$ is the function we're trying to construct from $F$.

> The erroneous proof of this statement runs as follows: "We apply the Peano induction postulate to $\mathrm{dom}{\ h}$. First of all, we are told that $h(e) = a$, and so $h$ is defined at $e$, i.e., $e \in \mathrm{dom}{\ h}$. And whenever $x \in \mathrm{dom}{\ h}$ then immediately $h(S(x)) = F(h(x))$, so $S(x) \in \mathrm{dom}{\ h}$ as well.
> Hence $\mathrm{dom}{\ h}$ is closed under $S$. It follows (by induction) that $\mathrm{dom}{\ h} = N$, i.e., $h$ is defined throughout $N$."

Enderton says that one issue is that the function $h$ here is talked about before defining it. To me, it seems like this can be fixed with a rewording (Jech's proof doesn't seem to have this issue). However, Enderton says that that can't be done, as the above proof doesn't utilize the facts that $e \notin \mathrm{ran}{\ S}$ and that $S$ is injective, which are necessary for the proof. Perhaps Jech's proof doesn't have to utilize this directly because it assumes a well-ordering and the analogous concept for these sets is baked into the principle of transfinite induction. Is this the case?

Then it would be the case that induction on $\omega$ is in a way weaker relative to recursion on $\omega$ than transfinite induction is to transfinite recursion, right? Or am I getting something mixed up here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me that the correct proof of the recursion theorem that Enderton gives is exactly the same strategy as Jech's proof. In fact, he defines $h(n) = y$ iff $v(n) = y$ for some "acceptable" $v$, where "acceptable" means that $v$ is a partial function defined on an initial segment of $\omega$ which satisfies the recursion criterion on its domain. This is obviously parallel to Jech's definition.

Enderton then proves that $h$ is a function,  $h$ has domain $\omega$, $h$ satisfies the recursion criterion, and $h$ is unique. And these are exactly the things that Jech proves / asserts after defining his $F$.

What Enderton is saying is wrong is a proof which tries to prove the "function" $h$ has domain $\omega$ without actually defining $h$ ("$h$ is talked about before defining it"). You say "this can be fixed with a rewording", but I think carefully defining $h$ as a union of "acceptable" approximating functions and carefully proving by induction that the resulting $h$ is actually a function goes beyond mere rewording.

Comment: Makes sense. What do you then think is the reason behind why Jech's proof can avoid mentioning that $e \notin \mathrm{ran} \ S$ and that $S$ is injective (or the analogous statements for arbitrary ordinals)? Do you agree it's because those properties are baked into the theorem of transfinite induction?

Comment: I wouldn't say that these properties are baked into transfinite induction... for example, the systems depicted in Enderton's Figures 16 (a) and (b) satisfy induction. Rather, these facts are used in the proofs that the object $F$ (or $h$) is really a function with domain $\mathrm{Ord}$ (or $\omega$).